# Implementing a binary search tree in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to become familiar with Clojure and so I've started to implement some basic algorithm and data structures. I currently have a problem with implementing a binary search tree. Here is my code:

```
(defstruct bst :left :right :key)

(defn add-bst [n bst-t]
  (cond
    (nil? bst-t) (struct-map bst :left nil :right nil :key n)
    (< n (:key bst-t))  (struct-map bst :left (add-bst n (:left bst-t))
                                :right (:right bst-t) :key (:key bst-t))
    (> n (:key bst-t))  (struct-map bst :left (:left bst-t)
                                :right (add-bst n (:right bst-t)) :key (:key bst-t))
    true bst-t))
```

I was trying to add random number into `BST` in the REPL, line so:

```
(exercise.new-ns/add-bst 5 nil)
```

But I get a `NullPointerException`, but I don't understand why I am getting this exception.  Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: If you are using at least Clojure 1.2, I would take a look at using `deftype` instead of `defstruct`. If you use `deftype`, you can also use protocols which will make `add-bst` and similar functions nicer because you can use `extend-type` on `nil`, effectively allowing your code to treat `nil` as if it were a BST node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is because you are re-using "bst" in your function parameters, which is confusing struct-map when the value is nil....

Try renaming the function parameter to something else.

Comment: I renamed the parameter and now I got the following error when trying to run this `(add-bst 0 (struct-map bst :left nil :right nil :key 5))`.  Here is the error: `#<CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: 5`

Comment: @haluk: in your struct-map calls you need to give the key as well as the value e.g. ":key (:key bst-t)" instead of just "(:key bst-t)"

Comment: all right, you are right, i fixed the code according to your tip.